# Compiling a pascal code

Tags: compilation, pascal

I have a Pascal code which is a part of a book, there are two files .inc and .pas. I need to compile them and i dont know how to proceed could you please help me with this.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. You can find one [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pascal+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: Well i am not a programmer , if the author gave the code, expecting a novice could compile it, i just thought it must be easy to use a third party software just to compile it and run with a little bit of help. If it  needs 2 weeks of my time looking at videos then no thank you

Comment: So a google search for "pascal" and "compiler" turned up nothing ? Really ?

Comment: A novice can compile it, provided they understand what *compile* means and how to do so. As I said, this is not a tutorial site. If it's not worth your effort to learn those things, hire someone to do the task for you. This site is for programmers.

Answer (score 2):

```
fpc [options] program
```

where `fpc` is pascal compiler, [options] are additional parameters and they are optional and program is your .pas file.

Comment: wouldnt i need some software to do this? I am sorry but i am starting from scratch, I have nothing

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 but I also use linux which ever makes it easy.

Comment: In linux, e.g. ubuntu you can install it like this: `sudo apt-get install fp-compiler-3.0.0`. In windows go to http://www.freepascal.org/download.var and download the required version. Then I recommend you to read tutorials on how to use it.